# Symbolic link and hard link questions

Tags: symlink, hard-link

Let's say /A/B/c.sh is symbolic linked to /X/Y/c.sh.

- If c.sh has the command "./SOMETHING", '.' means /A/B/ or /X/Y/?
- How about the hard link?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.` is actually the current working directory in either case; it has nothing to do with the directory holding the script:

```
[/tmp] $ echo "realpath ." > test.sh && chmod +x test.sh
[/tmp] $ /tmp/test.sh
/tmp
[/tmp] $ cd /usr/bin
[/usr/bin] $ /tmp/test.sh
/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Michael, but one place where it may matter is `$0` parameter.

I've seen scripts that investigate the name of `$0` and do different things based upon what symbolic name is used.

Comment: Not just scripts but complicated programs. Look at busybox for an example of a complicated program that matters what you call it as.

Answer (score 3):

The `.` in this case means the current working directly; the links' paths are irrelevant.  Referencing the file for execution or editing is essentially the same regardless of the type of link, even though there are several [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link) between them.

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't what you asked, it may be what you're looking for ...

You can use `"$0"` as a way to locate sub-scripts that are located in the same directory as the main script.

```
MYPATH="$(realpath "$0")"
MYDIR="$(dirname "$MYPATH")"
"$MYDIR/otherscript" ...
```

Since the main script is symlinked you need to dereference `$0` first, using `realpath`.  Although `dirname` returns `.` if its arg has no directory part, in this example `realpath` will already have turned the arg into an absolute path.